# Restore iPhone 7RED

Tags: iphone, restore, settings

How do I restore my phone to factory settings, I choose a password & cannot remember what - rather than the numeric code, as well as my fingerprint being on there.

Is it possible I can restore it without needing to plug in into iTunes please??

What combo of keys do I press to start my iPhone  back to factory settings??

Comment: Setting > Reset > erase all content and settings. But you must turn off find my iPhone first, which requires your iCloud/AppleID password

Comment: My iPhone is locked as I forget the password which I changed from being a numeric code & just forgot!! Is there any way I can restore it without the need to plug it into iTunes please??

Comment: Why can't you use iTunes?